# Linear maps, matrices, nullity and rank.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am currently trying to solve this question in my first year linear algebra course:

[image: question]

I understand that the assoc. matrix is the coefficients, eg for (a) [[1, -1];[5, 0]], but I'm not sure how to apply this to example (d).

I also know that:

$\dim \operatorname{Ker} T=\operatorname{nullity}T$

and

$\dim \operatorname{Im} T=\operatorname {rank} T$

but I don't understand how to find the values. I also know that by finding one, I can use the rank-nullity theorem to find the other.

I am not asking you to solve my question, I just want guidance with tackling rank and nullity and general approach to (d).

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the associated matrix to $T$ relative to the basis $(e_1,e_2)$ we should find the components of $T(e_k)$ for $k=1,2$ and then the matrix is 
$$[T(e_1)\;T(e_2)]$$
and in $(d)$ we have $T(e_1)=u_1$ and $T(e_2)=u_2$ hence the matrix of $T$ is
$$\left(\begin{matrix}-1&3\\3&3\end{matrix}\right)$$
and notice that the two columns of the above matrix i.e. the two vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$ are linearly independent hence the rank of this matrix is $2$ and then the nullity is $0$.

Comment: Can you explain why $u_1$ and $u_2$ being LI implies rankT=2?

Comment: The rank is the dimension of the image of $T$ which's spanned by $u_1$ and $u_2$ and since these vectors are LI then $(u_1,u_2)$ is a basis of the image hence the rank is $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The matrix for a linear transformation $T$ is $[T(e_1) T(e_2)]$. Can you use this to get the matrix for example (d)?